# Why there are several stages to enable pin change interrupts in AVR architecture

Tags: arduino, embedded, avr

In AVR architecture there are some interrupts that we need few lines of code to enable them. For example, pin change interrupts. But some interrupts have one step excluding global interrupt enable. For example, timer0 overflow interrupt, only to set 0th bit of TIMSK0 register. So, what are the advantages form designing architecture like that?

Comment: Some interrupts just have more configuration settings spread across different registers. or what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Yes. some interrupt have more configurations to set up. My question is why like that? For example in AVR atmega328p MCU. To activate pin 0 of portB we set both PCICR's PCIE0 bit and PCMSK0's PCINT0. why like that 2 steps to enable interrupt. What are the denifits.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the interrupts will have exactly the configuration bits/registers they need, and no more. In general, there is only one *enable* bit per interrupt vector.

To take your examples:

The pin change interrupts are quite simple and just need an enable bit per vector and a bitmask register (one bit per pin).

The timers are more complicated - while it's true as you say that to enable the timer0 overflow interrupt you only need to set `TOIE0` in `TIMSK0`, you still need to setup the timer correctly for this to be of use in your application, which may take several lines of code to accomplish.

In both cases, there is a *setup* step and an *enable* step.

The advantage of this is that you can setup the interrupts, but only enable them when required. This means:

- No processor cycles or RAM is wasted on interrupts running when not needed
- No power is wasted running interrupts when not needed
- Re-configuration of interrupts is possible when running, by disabling the interrupt, changing the configuration, and re-enabling it

All of these are useful for embedded software applications.

Answer (score 1):

In general, [jfowkes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54289229/10641561) explains how the setup for each interrupt (ADC, timer, pin-change, data tx, EEPROM, ...) may differ but there is one actual line of code enabling each individual interrupt.

If you have a counterexample, that would be easier to clarify.

---

A lot of information about pin-change interrupts is condensed onto this page:
http://medesign.seas.upenn.edu/index.php/Guides/MaEvArM-pcint

It's specific to one AVR chipset, but it should give you a little more information.

Normally, the architecture design is kept as simple as possible, because that's also what is easiest to design and etch at the transistor level. If you watch the MIT 6.004 lectures, [specifically #20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WLOCFHDeDQ), they detail how/why instruction sets are designed. Or, you can check out http://www.avr-tutorials.com/interrupts/about-avr-8-bit-microcontrollers-interrupts. Basically, one dedicated circuit for interrupts (with one bit controlling whether each interrupt signal is passed or not) makes it easy to store the current program counter and service the interrupt.